# Removing small polygon gaps in Shapely polygon?

Tags: polygon, shapely, slivers, gap

I know this issue has been addressed before with different software, but how do I do it with Shapely?

I have a polygon with a very small gap on the interior of the shape:

[image: gap]

**Here is a close up:**

[image: gapClose]

The polygon is valid so I can't use the buffer trick, and simplifying the polygon also doesn't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The thing you are looking at is a sliver geometry. Similar to [@sgillies's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/120297/115), except use a few [buffer parameters](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.buffer) to control the chiselled geometry shape:

```
import json
from shapely.geometry import shape, JOIN_STYLE
eps = 0.001  # epsilon that is approx. the width of slivers, e.g. 1 mm

# Load the original polygon from GeoJSON
poly = shape(json.loads('{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[...]]]}'))

# Here's the algorithm
fx = poly.buffer(eps, 1, join_style=JOIN_STYLE.mitre).buffer(-eps, 1, join_style=JOIN_STYLE.mitre)

# Compare number of vertices in the exterior LinearRing
print(len(poly.exterior.coords))  # 136
print(len(fx.exterior.coords))    # 135
```

Note that the fixed `fx` geometry has one less coordinate, which was the dangling sliver. Also note that some of the vertices may have wiggled around from their original position, usually several times less than `eps`.

Answer (score 7):

Try dilating and eroding by a small factor (`eps`).

```
   geom.buffer(eps).buffer(-eps)
```